# how use switch case range JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to using siwtch case JavaScript like this

```
 <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
  var n=new Date();
  var jam=n.getHours();
  switch (jam) {
  case (jam>='17'):
    time = "sleep";
    break;
   case (jam<'17'):
    time = "work";
    break;     
   }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "This Time for " + time;
  </script>
```

but this didn't appear anything

Comment: For this case you should use `If() else` state not `switch() case`

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_switch.asp read how switch case works. You need to use if else

Comment: Why aren't you using a simple `if else` statement in this case? Otherwise your expression returns a `boolean` and not a number, so the switch case never matches. And also you are comparing integers, so don't use the quotes.

Comment: define variable `time`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switch on ranges of integers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619832/switch-on-ranges-of-integers-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

You are using `switch()case` in incorrect way. Because `switch` is used when you are trying to check states, but not ranges. If you want to check ranges, you'd rather use `if()else` state like this:

```
<p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
  var n=new Date();
  var jam=n.getHours();

  if ( parseInt(jam) >= 17){
    time = "sleep";
  } else if ( parseInt(jam) <17)
    time = "work";
  } else {
    time = " play :) "
  }

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "This Time for " + time;
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the switch case if you are trying to check range using `switch`, else you have to go for the traditional `if else` condition. I have modified the code as per your requirement. Please check this one.

```html
 <html>
     <body>
         <p id="demo"></p>

         <script>
                var n=new Date();
                var jam=n.getHours();
                var time = "";
                switch (true) {
                       case (jam>=17):
                              time = "sleep";
                              break;
                       case (jam<17):
                              time = "work";
                              break;     
                 }
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "This Time for " + time;
         </script>
         </body>
  </html>
```

Using if else.

```html
    <html>
         <body>
             <p id="demo"></p>

             <script>
                    var n=new Date();
                    var jam=n.getHours();
                    var time = "";
                    
                    if (jam>=17){
                       time = "sleep";
                    }
                                  
                    else if (jam<17){
                       time = "work";
                    }   
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "This Time for " + time;
             </script>
             </body>
      </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `case` and use a condition in the case statement and `true` in the select part.

The use a fall trough style to check smalles value first and the bigger values. The check must use numbers, not strings as in the example.

at least you coluld use a default branch and assign somthing default like, which works when all other condition are not met.

```js
var n = new Date(),
    jam = n.getHours(),
    time = '';

switch (true) {
    case (jam < 9):  // this leads to if (true === (jam < 9)) { ...
        time = "coffee";
        break;
    case (jam < 17):
        time = "work";
        break;
    case (jam < 19):
        time = "relaxing";
        break;
    default:
        time = "sleep";
}
console.log("This Time for " + time);
console.log(jam);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed your code, here is the js fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/qkpmkzoh/

And the fixed code is this.

```
  var n=new Date();
  var jam=n.getHours();
  var time = "";
  console.log(jam);
  switch (true) {
  case jam>=17:
    time = "sleep";
    break;
   case jam<17:
    time = "work";
    break;     
   }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "This Time for " + time
```

However I would recommend you to use if else, as it makes the code more readable

```
  var n=new Date();
  var jam=n.getHours();
  var time = "";
  console.log(jam);
  if (jam>=17){
   time = "sleep";
  }
    else if(jam<17) {
    time = "work";
  }
```