# Struggling with function factory & closure

Tags: javascript, function, scope, closures

After a long time I played around with plain JS again. And I'm struggling in fixing a closure problem.

**Task:** I'm using a function factory to set params for a returned function which I then want to call.

**Problem:** As far as I understand the params are passed by reference and when the execution context is popped off the stack, the variables lead to undefined memory space. How can I make this work?

```js
    function changeColorConstructor(greenLimit, redLimit) {
        var greenLimit = greenLimit;
        var redLimit = redLimit;
        console.log('1. Green Limit in Constructor shell: ' + greenLimit);
        
        return function(metric) {
          var color;
    
          console.log('3. Green Limit in returned function: ' + greenLimit);
    
          switch(metric) {
            case metric >= greenLimit:
              console.log('Green');
              color = '#56C621'; // green
              break;
            case metric < greenLimit && metric > redLimit:
              console.log('Yellow');
              color = '#F2E607'; // yellow
              break;
            case metric <= redLimit:
              console.log('Red');
              color = '#C64C20'; // red
              break;
            default:
              color = '#C0C0C0'
              break;
          }
          return color;
        }
    
      }
    
      var indexColor = changeColorConstructor(5000, 10000);
      console.log('2. Returned function: ' + indexColor);
    
      console.log('4. Output from production function: ' + indexColor(5000));
```

Comment: your switch cases don't look right to me...

Comment: "*the variables lead to undefined memory space*" - No, that's not how JavaScript works. Describe your actual problem, not what you think the problem is.

Comment: Why are you creating local variables with the same name as the ones passed in parameters?

Comment: I think you're missing the /new/ keyword when assigning the function/object to indexColor --- var indexColor = new changeColorConstructor(5000, 10000); ---  Otherwise, indexColor is a reference to the function rather than it's own thing.

Comment: @Doug No, `indexColor` will be the function returned by `changeColorConstructor`, which is fine (and what the OP is trying to do). It's a function generator.

Comment: Thanks for all your input. Indeed the switch statement was off. Good personal learning: Keeping an open mind and don't prematurely diagnose the issue.

Comment: Don't edit your question with the solution. If you want to answer your own question, post it as an answer.

Comment: @Juri Please consider the idea that this isn't a good use of the switch statement for reasons I list in my comment on the answer, and as discussed in the accepted answer of the linked question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, your problem is not with closures or function factories, but with `switch`:

```
switch(metric) {
    case metric >= greenLimit:
```

This code compares `metric` to the result of `metric >= greenLimit`, i.e. it works like `if (metric == (metric >= greenLimit))`.

`metric >= greenLimit` is either `true` or `false`, so comparing this to `metric` doesn't make much sense.

In the snippet below I've replaced your `switch` statement by the `if` / `else` cascade you intended, and I've removed the nonsensical `var greenLimit = greenLimit;` assignments.

```js
function changeColorConstructor(greenLimit, redLimit) {
    console.log('1. Green Limit in Constructor shell: ' + greenLimit);

    return function (metric) {
        var color;

        console.log('3. Green Limit in returned function: ' + greenLimit);

        if (metric >= greenLimit) {
            console.log('Green');
            color = '#56C621'; // green
        } else if (metric < greenLimit && metric > redLimit) {
            console.log('Yellow');
            color = '#F2E607'; // yellow
        } else if (metric <= redLimit) {
            console.log('Red');
            color = '#C64C20'; // red
        } else {
            color = '#C0C0C0'
        }
        return color;
    };
}

var indexColor = changeColorConstructor(5000, 10000);
console.log('2. Returned function: ' + indexColor);

console.log('4. Output from production function: ' + indexColor(5000));
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get 'Green' to print out when I used this switch-case trick found at: [Switch on ranges of integers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619832/switch-on-ranges-of-integers-in-javascript)

Basically, set the switch to test against to a boolean 'true' to compare ranges in a case.

```js
    function changeColorConstructor(greenLimit, redLimit) {
        var greenLimit = greenLimit;
        var redLimit = redLimit;
        console.log('1. Green Limit in Constructor shell: ' + greenLimit);
        
        return function(metric) {
          var color;
    
          console.log('3. Green Limit in returned function: ' + greenLimit);
    
          switch(true) {
            case metric >= greenLimit:
              console.log('Green');
              color = '#56C621'; // green
              break;
            case metric < greenLimit && metric > redLimit:
              console.log('Yellow');
              color = '#F2E607'; // yellow
              break;
            case metric <= redLimit:
              console.log('Red');
              color = '#C64C20'; // red
              break;
            default:
              color = '#C0C0C0'
              break;
          }
          return color;
        }
    
      }
    
      var indexColor = changeColorConstructor(5000, 10000);
      console.log('2. Returned function: ' + indexColor);
    
      console.log('4. Output from production function: ' + indexColor(5000));
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it's brittle, and allows people to *very* easily think they could re-order the cases, change values without regard to execution order, etc. This is not a good use for a `switch` as discussed in several comments at the linked question.

Comment: @DaveNewton I agree -- it was neat to see a work around to the range challenge in switch-cases, but I like melpomene 's solution by converting it to a series of if-else statements.

Comment: you are right, in this case the solution with an if/else is better than hacking the switch statement.