# Switch Statement Not Executing Corresponding Blocks

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, console.log

Here is my code

```
var randomNumber = Math.ceil(100 * Math.random());

switch (randomNumber) {
case (randomNumber < 20):
    console.log("The number is less than 20");
    break;
case (randomNumber => 20 && randomNumber < 50):
    console.log("The number is between 20 and 50");
    break;
case (randomNumber => 50 && randomNumber < 75):
    console.log("The number is between 50 and 75");
    break;
default:
    console.log("The number is greater than 75");
    break;
}

console.log(randomNumber);
```

The first part simply declares a new binding and assigns it a random integer value between 1 and 100.

The second part, the switch statement, is supposed to send a particular message, depending on the condition, the value of the randomNumber binding.

For some reason--I'm not sure why--it only executes the code corresponding to the `default` keyword. And, of course, it also executes the last statement, which prints the value of the binding to the browser console.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Here is the description of the [Javascript switch statement](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp). Check the part under *This is how it works:...*.

Comment: As Nina mentions, you're treating `switch` as if it were if/else if conditional blocks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619832/switch-on-ranges-of-integers-in-javascript)  to understand what Nina is suggesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`switch` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) uses a [strict comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) and you need to check against `true`.

Then you could check only the upper bound, because you checked already the lower one.

```js
var randomNumber = Math.ceil(100 * Math.random());

switch (true) {
    case randomNumber < 20:
        console.log("The number is less than 20");
        break;
    case randomNumber < 50:
        console.log("The number is between 20 and 50");
        break;
    case randomNumber < 75:
        console.log("The number is between 50 and 75");
        break;
    default:
        console.log("The number is greater than 75");
        break;
}

console.log(randomNumber);
```

Comment: But really, if this is the scenario, an `if` is probably the better construct to use.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, it really depends, if only a value has to be returned, or some more statements have to ecexuted, ...

Comment: I'm actually reading Eloquent JavaScript, and the author seemed to imply that the if statement and the switch statement were interchangeable. It seems there is more nuance. Thanks, Nina! (-: